# How can I layout a sidebar or pullquote?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs in a fixed width layout: a, b, c, and d, and they are ordered in the html like this:

```
<div id="a">
</div>
<div id="b">
</div>
<div id="c">
</div>
<div id="d">
</div>
```

Using CSS, I want them to be laid out with divs a, b, and d in a vertical column, and div c to the right of and top-aligned with div b, like this:

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
bbbccc
bbbccc
bbbccc
ddd
ddd
ddd
```

I need this layout to work even though the divs contain unknown content, and so could be of varying length:

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
bbbccc
bbbccc
dddccc
dddccc
ddd
```

or:

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
bbbccc
bbb
bbb
ddd
ddd
ddd
```

or even (if possible):

```
aaa
aaa
bbbccc
dddccc
eeeccc
eee
```

I can't simply float div c to the right and then move it up, because, without using Javascript, I don't know the height of div b, and so don't know how much to move it up by.

Is this possible in HTML and CSS, without reordering the divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a {
  clear: both;
}
b {
  float: left;
}
c {
  float: right;
}
d, e {
  clear: left;
}
```

Would probably solve it (not tested).